# Use a static library in application that uses precompiled headers

Tags: visual-c++, precompiled-headers

My application uses precompiled headers and I am trying to use a static library which does not use precompiled headers.

The problem is that I am getting a bunch of warning: when attempting to rebuild my application:

```
#include "some_library_hdr.h"': skipped when looking for precompiled header use
Add directive to 'stdafx.h' or rebuild precompiled header
```

When building my static library, I was unable to build it if the 'precompiled header' option was specified so I just unchecked it.

Can someone tell me what options are available for solving this problem?

**Update**

As suggested by Hans Passant, I turned off the application's precompiled header option but noticed that time to rebuild took about twice as long as before.

This is my first time creating a static library for inclusion into an application.  What I had done previously was to copy the source files into a project but this time I had decided to keep all of that redundant code in a single location (the static lib).

1) Must static libraries be created with precompiled headers turned off?

2) If I use a **static library** in my application, I must turn off its precompiled headers as well?

3) I've never created a **shared dll**, but if I do that, can I still benefit from precompiled headers in my application?

Thank you

Comment: When the library source code does not use a precompiled header then turning the option off is of course the correct thing to do.

Comment: @HansPassant, I did what you suggested an my application builds once again.  Thank you.